# Adding Spans around HTML with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have been tring to strip out some unnesesary colons that are being produced within a set of HTML. I do not have any control over the output of the HTML, and only wish to add a SPAN with a class around the problematic colons so that I can hide them with CSS.
The colons appear between the spans of "columnName" and "columnValue" like so -

```
<span id="columnName">Manufacturer Item</span>: <span id="columnValue">
```

I had found a JQuery function that I thought would help, but have not had any luck with it...and am sure I have overlooked something..

```
function removeStupidGridColons(){
$(div:contains(">: <")').html(function(index, oldHTML) {
    return oldHTML.replace(/(>: <)/g, '><span class="StupidColon">$&</span><');
});
}
$(document).ready(function(){


        removeStupidGridColons();
});
```

Lastly here is a full clip of the HTML.....

```
            <div id="itemsListGridView">


                    <div class="itemGridView" style="width:24%; border-right: 1px solid #D7D7D7;"><div class="itemGridViewImg" style="height:212px;"><a href="#" onclick="viewDetails(itemDetailForm, 1948, 'EACH', '1', 1, '', '19571','','19571')"><img src="/storefrontCommerce/imageContent.do?contentKey=92fe3487-6484-4c86-942d-1a481d8f5ae6&size=GALLERY&fileName=19571.jpg" alt="19571"/></a></div><div id="itm_manufitem1948_EACH1" class="itemGridViewDetails"><span id="columnName">Manufacturer Item</span>: <span id="columnValue">19571</A></span></div><div id="itm_numlink1948_EACH1" class="itemGridViewDetails"><span id="columnName">Item Number Link</span>: <span id="columnValue"><A href="#" onclick="viewDetails(itemDetailForm, 1948, 'EACH', '1', 1, '', '19571','','19571')">19571</A></span></div><div id="calc_avail_dft1948_EACH1" class="itemGridViewDetails"><span id="columnName">Quantity Avail (Dft Whse)</span>: <span id="columnValue">33</span></div><div id="avail_calc_dft_flag1948_EACH1" class="itemGridViewDetails"><span id="columnName">Availability (Dft Whse)</span>: <span id="columnValue"><div class="InStockMsg">Stock</div></span></div><div id="itm_manufacturer1948_EACH1" class="itemGridViewDetails"><span id="columnName">Manufacturer</span>: <span id="columnValue">LA-CO</A></span></div><div id="calc_avail1948_EACH1" class="itemGridViewDetails"><span id="columnName">Company Available</span>: <span id="columnValue">90</span></div><div id="avail_calc_flag1948_EACH1" class="itemGridViewDetails"><span id="columnName">Availability Flag</span>: <span id="columnValue"><div class="InStockMsg">Stock</div></span></div><div id="itm_proddesc1948_EACH1" class="itemGridViewDetails"><span id="columnName">Description</span>: <span id="columnValue">Epoxy-Stik Multi-Purpose Epoxy Putty; Fixes Leaks In Pipes, Fittings, Sheet Metal and Ducts; 4 Oz Tube</span></div><div id="calc_price1948_EACH1" class="itemGridViewDetails"><span id="columnName">Sell Price</span>: <span id="columnValue">$8.40&nbsp;EACH</span></div><div class="addToCartButton"></div><input type="button" class="button addToCartButton" onclick="ajaxcartAdd(itemDetailForm, '1948', 'EACH', '1', 1,'', true);" value="Add to Cart" /></div>


                    <div class="itemGridView" style="width:24%; border-right: 1px solid #D7D7D7;"><div class="itemGridViewImg" style="height:212px;"><a href="#" onclick="viewDetails(itemDetailForm, 979, 'EACH', '1', 1, '', '11575','','11575')"><img src="/storefrontCommerce/imageContent.do?contentKey=d80c7c33-aba6-483e-973c-06b7987ac1af&size=GALLERY&fileName=11575.jpg" alt="11575"/></a></div><div id="itm_manufitem979_EACH1" class="itemGridViewDetails"><span id="columnName">Manufacturer Item</span>: <span id="columnValue">11575</A></span></div><div id="itm_numlink979_EACH1" class="itemGridViewDetails"><span id="columnName">Item Number Link</span>: <span id="columnValue"><A href="#" onclick="viewDetails(itemDetailForm, 979, 'EACH', '1', 1, '', '11575','','11575')">11575</A></span></div><div id="calc_avail_dft979_EACH1" class="itemGridViewDetails"><span id="columnName">Quantity Avail (Dft Whse)</span>: <span id="columnValue">9</span></div><div id="avail_calc_dft_flag979_EACH1" class="itemGridViewDetails"><span id="columnName">Availability (Dft Whse)</span>: <span id="columnValue"><div class="InStockMsg">Stock</div></span></div><div id="itm_manufacturer979_EACH1" class="itemGridViewDetails"><span id="columnName">Manufacturer</span>: <span id="columnValue">LA-CO</A></span></div><div id="calc_avail979_EACH1" class="itemGridViewDetails"><span id="columnName">Company Available</span>: <span id="columnValue">44</span></div><div id="avail_calc_flag979_EACH1" class="itemGridViewDetails"><span id="columnName">Availability Flag</span>: <span id="columnValue"><div class="InStockMsg">Stock</div></span></div><div id="itm_proddesc979_EACH1" class="itemGridViewDetails"><span id="columnName">Description</span>: <span id="columnValue">Epoxy Sealer; Heat-Seal Stik; For Aluminum And Copper Repair; Premixed Epoxy; 3/8 Oz Tube</span></div><div id="calc_price979_EACH1" class="itemGridViewDetails"><span id="columnName">Sell Price</span>: <span id="columnValue">$13.64&nbsp;EACH</span></div><div class="addToCartButton"></div><input type="button" class="button addToCartButton" onclick="ajaxcartAdd(itemDetailForm, '979', 'EACH', '1', 1,'', true);" value="Add to Cart" /></div>


            </div>
```

Thank you in advance for any help on this....it is appreciated.

```js
function removeStupidGridColons(){
$(div:contains(">: <")').html(function(index, oldHTML) {
    return oldHTML.replace(/(>: <)/g, '><span class="StupidColon">$&</span><');
});
}
$(document).ready(function(){


        removeStupidGridColons();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="itemsListGridView">
                    <div class="itemGridView" style="width:24%; border-right: 1px solid #D7D7D7;"><div class="itemGridViewImg" style="height:212px;"><a href="#" onclick="viewDetails(itemDetailForm, 1948, 'EACH', '1', 1, '', '19571','','19571')"><img src="/storefrontCommerce/imageContent.do?contentKey=92fe3487-6484-4c86-942d-1a481d8f5ae6&size=GALLERY&fileName=19571.jpg" alt="19571"/></a></div><div id="itm_manufitem1948_EACH1" class="itemGridViewDetails"><span id="columnName">Manufacturer Item</span>: <span id="columnValue">19571</A></span></div><div id="itm_numlink1948_EACH1" class="itemGridViewDetails"><span id="columnName">Item Number Link</span>: <span id="columnValue"><A href="#" onclick="viewDetails(itemDetailForm, 1948, 'EACH', '1', 1, '', '19571','','19571')">19571</A></span></div><div id="calc_avail_dft1948_EACH1" class="itemGridViewDetails"><span id="columnName">Quantity Avail (Dft Whse)</span>: <span id="columnValue">33</span></div><div id="avail_calc_dft_flag1948_EACH1" class="itemGridViewDetails"><span id="columnName">Availability (Dft Whse)</span>: <span id="columnValue"><div class="InStockMsg">Stock</div></span></div><div id="itm_manufacturer1948_EACH1" class="itemGridViewDetails"><span id="columnName">Manufacturer</span>: <span id="columnValue">LA-CO</A></span></div><div id="calc_avail1948_EACH1" class="itemGridViewDetails"><span id="columnName">Company Available</span>: <span id="columnValue">90</span></div><div id="avail_calc_flag1948_EACH1" class="itemGridViewDetails"><span id="columnName">Availability Flag</span>: <span id="columnValue"><div class="InStockMsg">Stock</div></span></div><div id="itm_proddesc1948_EACH1" class="itemGridViewDetails"><span id="columnName">Description</span>: <span id="columnValue">Epoxy-Stik Multi-Purpose Epoxy Putty; Fixes Leaks In Pipes, Fittings, Sheet Metal and Ducts; 4 Oz Tube</span></div><div id="calc_price1948_EACH1" class="itemGridViewDetails"><span id="columnName">Sell Price</span>: <span id="columnValue">$8.40&nbsp;EACH</span></div><div class="addToCartButton"></div><input type="button" class="button addToCartButton" onclick="ajaxcartAdd(itemDetailForm, '1948', 'EACH', '1', 1,'', true);" value="Add to Cart" /></div>


                    <div class="itemGridView" style="width:24%; border-right: 1px solid #D7D7D7;"><div class="itemGridViewImg" style="height:212px;"><a href="#" onclick="viewDetails(itemDetailForm, 979, 'EACH', '1', 1, '', '11575','','11575')"><img src="/storefrontCommerce/imageContent.do?contentKey=d80c7c33-aba6-483e-973c-06b7987ac1af&size=GALLERY&fileName=11575.jpg" alt="11575"/></a></div><div id="itm_manufitem979_EACH1" class="itemGridViewDetails"><span id="columnName">Manufacturer Item</span>: <span id="columnValue">11575</A></span></div><div id="itm_numlink979_EACH1" class="itemGridViewDetails"><span id="columnName">Item Number Link</span>: <span id="columnValue"><A href="#" onclick="viewDetails(itemDetailForm, 979, 'EACH', '1', 1, '', '11575','','11575')">11575</A></span></div><div id="calc_avail_dft979_EACH1" class="itemGridViewDetails"><span id="columnName">Quantity Avail (Dft Whse)</span>: <span id="columnValue">9</span></div><div id="avail_calc_dft_flag979_EACH1" class="itemGridViewDetails"><span id="columnName">Availability (Dft Whse)</span>: <span id="columnValue"><div class="InStockMsg">Stock</div></span></div><div id="itm_manufacturer979_EACH1" class="itemGridViewDetails"><span id="columnName">Manufacturer</span>: <span id="columnValue">LA-CO</A></span></div><div id="calc_avail979_EACH1" class="itemGridViewDetails"><span id="columnName">Company Available</span>: <span id="columnValue">44</span></div><div id="avail_calc_flag979_EACH1" class="itemGridViewDetails"><span id="columnName">Availability Flag</span>: <span id="columnValue"><div class="InStockMsg">Stock</div></span></div><div id="itm_proddesc979_EACH1" class="itemGridViewDetails"><span id="columnName">Description</span>: <span id="columnValue">Epoxy Sealer; Heat-Seal Stik; For Aluminum And Copper Repair; Premixed Epoxy; 3/8 Oz Tube</span></div><div id="calc_price979_EACH1" class="itemGridViewDetails"><span id="columnName">Sell Price</span>: <span id="columnValue">$13.64&nbsp;EACH</span></div><div class="addToCartButton"></div><input type="button" class="button addToCartButton" onclick="ajaxcartAdd(itemDetailForm, '979', 'EACH', '1', 1,'', true);" value="Add to Cart" /></div>


            </div>
```

Comment: `$(div:contains(">: <")'` , so here's the thing about what you are trying to do.  When you run javascript/jQuery against the DOM, you are not changing html.  You are changing the DOM (Document Object Model).  All the markup has been parsed and loaded into the DOM.  As such, the div does not contain the > or < part of the tags.  Those tags are now objects, so you can't string match against them like that in the DOM.  Something to be aware of when developing.

Comment: Also you have invalid markup.  You cannot repeat ids like "columnName" and "columnValue".

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Taplar I was not aware of this....as far as the  invalid markup is not something that I can control....I have put a request in with the developers to change/correct it, but they show little interest in doing that any time soon.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an each function

```
   var item = $('.itemGridViewDetails');
       item.each(function(){
           var $string = $(this).html();
           $newString = $string.replace(/(>: <)/g, '><span class="StupidColon">:</span><');
        $(this).replaceWith($newString);
   });
```

Comment: Thank you for the input...I cannot seem to get this to work in JSFiddle...

Comment: Updated the code above, here's a working Fiddle-  https://jsfiddle.net/Jim_Miraidev/af4b8vhp/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
$(".itemGridViewDetails").contents().filter(function () {
     return this.nodeType === 3; 
}).wrap("<span class='red-text'></span>");
```

```css
.red-text{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="itm_manufitem1948_EACH1" class="itemGridViewDetails">
  <span id="columnName">Manufacturer Item</span>: <span id="columnValue">A</span>
</div>
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cas5xgff/2/

Here is the reference for `noteType`: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType